# Strange server access logs

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Every morning, I monitor access logs to filter out bots and malicious attempts to break in. I keep noticing this same type of log.

Example output (website and IP address are hidden):

```
8232 xxx.xxx.xx.xx - - [11/Oct/2018:04:14:11 -0500] <thewebsite>.com "GET /util/login.aspx HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" "-"
```

First, /util/login.aspx does not exist, so they are getting redirected. This does not look like a typical crawler since they are trying to access a login page.

Could someone shed some light on what a typical script kiddie might be doing? It's always the **exact same** file path (/util/login.aspx). I have tools in place to mitigate this, but I would like to know if anyone has ever seen this type of activity with what appears to be a typical ASP.NET login page. We use Linux servers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the internet, where everyone will try to poke your server for security holes. You could install and configure some script like fail2ban to filter a bit those request, but I would ignore them else

Comment: I understand that. I guess I was just trying to get some intel on what they might be using to make these attempts. I created a new fail2ban jail definition. I'll see if it works. I'm not as concerned with break-ins as I am with server load. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: You can look for the file name on google to see dome insigh, I know wordpress default file are often what I see scanned usually

Comment: Junk characters as IPs and bogus names are not very readable. Consider not obfuscating IPs or names. If you must, make it obvious with RFC documentation standards like TEST-NET subnets or example.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical sysadmin response to repeated unsuccessful bogus requests is to block and be done with it. Maybe move resources unnecessarily facing externally into an internal zone.

A login page for a platform you don't have is obviously invalid, and possibly an exploit attempt. If you want actual threat intelligence on this, invest in your security organization. Knowing various exploits, looking up IP reputation scores, and correlating with recent botnets are some jobs for a security analyst.

Comment: Thank you John. We don't have a security team, and I'm just a Jr Sys Admin in the process of learning the ropes. I was just gathering experiences from others who may have seen this type of thing, and since I've seen that url path many times from different IPs, I was just wondering what type of exploit this could be related to. Being in a small company (barely 100 ppl), I am pretty much the security analyst as well once the Sr Sys Admin retires in 1 year. I will take your answer and expand my learning from there. Again, thank you.